# Can an MVC @helper be called from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

As per the title, can an MVC @helper function be called from javascript/JQuery?

```
@helper DoStuff(string someValue) {

         //do some stuff   
        }
```

then later on:

```
$("#MyDropdown").on("change", function() {

        @DoStuff('blah')

    });
```

Comment: No, but you can call a helper while generating your javascript... which is not really at all the same thing.

Comment: You can quote it, but razor code is parsed on the server before its sent to the browser so might be a bit pointless

Comment: In addition to @StephenMuecke , that javascript must be a part of your .cshtml page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it can't.

The reason for this is because ASP.NET MVC parses the Razor Syntax and compiles it down to C#; where was the Javascript is executed by the visitor's browser.

If you wish to execute a Razor helper like you demonstrate in your question then you're going to need to perform an AJAX call to a controller action and render the helper's output to HTML.